# Sonar maven integration

Tags: sonarqube

I have followed the [directions to integrate Sonar with Maven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Install+Sonar) - altered settings.xml to include sonar repository at:

**http: //localhost:9000/deploy/maven**

and I have verified I am able to see the readme.txt file at:

**http: //localhost:9000/deploy/maven/README.txt**

but when running `sonar:sonar` I keep getting the following message:

```
[INFO] [sonar:sonar]
[INFO] Sonar host: http: //localhost:9000
[INFO] Sonar version: 1.7
Downloading: http: //localhost:9000/deploy/maven/org/codehaus/sonar/runtime/sonar
-core-maven-plugin/20090803213910/sonar-core-maven-plugin-20090803213910.pom
Downloading: http: //<MY SERVER URL>:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/
sonar/runtime/sonar-core-maven-plugin/20090803213910/sonar-core-maven-plugin-200
90803213910.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.codehaus.sonar.runtime:s
onar-core-maven-plugin': POM 'org.codehaus.sonar.runtime:sonar-core-maven-plugin
' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.codehaus.sonar.runtime:sonar-core-maven-plugin:pom:20090803213910
```

from the specified remote repositories:

sonar (http: //localhost:9000/deploy/maven),

nexus (http: //:8081/nexus/content/groups/public),

for project org.codehaus.sonar.runtime:sonar-core-maven-plugin
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

1.The maven plugins required to run sonar on your localhost reside @ http://localhost:9000/deploy/maven/........... ( they are bundled with your sonar installation )

2.to pick the plugins(bundled with your sonar installation)
  you need to execute 'mvn  sonar:sonar ' at the root of your application

3.You need not depend on the nexus repositories of your company

4.When you do not want to depend on the nexus repositories, you need to mirror out 'sonar' in the mirror declaration of your settings.xml
  => *,!sonar  include this !sonar in your mirror definitions

5. declare http://localhost:9000 in one of your active profiles
6. Start your sonar server

Now execute the command 'mvn sonar:sonar' ,the maven-sonar plugins  are picked from local sonar installation..

Good Luck ,
aravind.dev

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for replying to this old thread..just thought [this link](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-806?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs) may point to the solution.

Basically, you could try modifying the  tag in your maven setting.xml (inside the .m2 folder required for maven) as follows:

```
<mirrorOf>*,!sonar</mirrorOf>
```

It tells maven to avoid using your normal repository for any sonar download task

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue was, but by upgrading to version 1.9.2 (I was trying to get 1.7 working as it is currently running on another server) and removing the sonar-maven-plugin definition in the project POM, running mvn sonar:sonar was able to execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

localhost is not a remote host; localhost is an alias for the machine you're on.  so it's trying to download the stuff from a maven repository server running on your machine.

Comment: Correct, the Sonar service I am trying to upload results to is running on the same machine I am running mvn sonar:sonar.  I also have Nexus installed on this machine (as shown in the original post), but for debugging purposes to solve this problem I commented out the mirror configuration in Maven settings.xml - same results.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to resolve the issue by upgrading to maven 3 and sonar 2.4. I also found that running maven with the option (-U) for update can help.